# Writing in file current working directory without carriage return or other characters (like space)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, save

I'm trying to write a file with a batch script, that once run has to type in a file named configurationFile.txt the current working directory. The main problem are all the characters that windows add after the cd command. Here is my example

```
set "var=%cd%"
echo %var%
if exist configurationFile.txt (
    rem file exists
) else (
    echo %var%>configurationFile.txt
)
set Build=<configurationFile.txt
```

This code creates the configurationFile.txt if this does not exists, but adding new lines and other characters. I have to use this file in a linux script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire posted code could be replaced with this:

```sh
@Set "Build=%CD%"
@Echo(%Build%
@If Not Exist "configurationFile.txt" Set /P "=%Build%" 0<NUL 1>"configurationFile.txt"
```

Or this:

```sh
@Echo(%CD%
@If Not Exist "configurationFile.txt" Set /P "=%CD%" 0<NUL 1>"configurationFile.txt"
@Set /P "Build=" 0<"configurationFile.txt"
```

Or doing it your way:

```sh
@Set "var=%CD%"
@Echo(%var%
@If Exist "configurationFile.txt" (
    Rem file exists code goes here
) Else (
    Set /P "=%var%" 0<NUL 1>"configurationFile.txt"
)
@Set /P "Build=" 0<"configurationFile.txt"
```